# How to avoid merging in R

Tags: r

I have two vectors, `arg1` and `arg2` and a data frame `df`.

```
arg1 <- c(1, 1, 2, 2)
arg2 <- c(1, 2, 1, 2)

df <- data.frame(a <- c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4))
```

I want to include the informations of `arg1` and `arg2` in my data frame but without merge.
The key assignment, here, is to link the first value of `arg1` or `arg2` with the value 1 of a, the second value of `arg1` or `arg2` with the value 2 of a, etc..

final output:

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4),
             d = c(1, 1, 1, 1 ,2, 2, 2, 2),
             e = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2))
```

If I was in the case of unicity of arg1 and arg2, I would do:

```
df$d <- as.character(factor(a, labels = arg1))
```

The classic way I think to do it is to convert `arg1` and `arg2` as a dataframe and merge with df. But this solution seems a bit heavy. Is there a way to do it just with vector assignment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make use of factors stored as integers:

```
i <- as.integer(factor(df$a, levels = unique(df$a)))
cbind(df, 
      d = arg1[i],
      e = arg2[i])
#  a d e
#1 1 1 1
#2 1 1 1
#3 2 1 2
#4 2 1 2
#5 3 2 1
#6 3 2 1
#7 4 2 2
#8 4 2 2
```

I assume that there may be different values than 1:4 in column `a` and in that case this would match the first unique value in `a` to the first value in `arg1` and `arg2`, respectively.

---

As @A.Webb notes in the comments, it would be even easier to use

```
i <- match(df$a,unique(df$a))
```

instead of converting to factor and integer.

Comment: Why convert to factor and then back to integer if `a` is already an integer? e.g., `cbind(df, d = arg1[df$a], e = arg2[df$a])` should return the same.

Comment: @DavidArenburg, because there may be different values than 1:4 in a, no?

Comment: @YCR, I made a small edit - please note. This is necessary to ensure correct ordering if values in "a" were not ordered ascending

Answer (score 2):

We can use `Map`

```
do.call(rbind, Map(cbind, split(df$a, df$a),
               d=arg1, e= arg2))
```

---

Or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    mutate(d=arg1[a], e= arg2[a])
```

---

Or with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, c('d', 'e') := list(a,arg1[.GRP], arg2[.GRP]) ,.(a)]
```

Comment: The `dplyr` one seems like an awfully over-complicated version of `transform(df, d = arg1[a], e = arg2[a])`

Comment: @DavidArenburg But, the catch is that it uses the magic operator `%>%`

Comment: And I guess you could just do `setDT(df)[, c('b', 'd') := .(arg1[a], arg2[a])]` with `data.table`, no?

Comment: @DavidArenburg Yes, but just in case, 'a' column is `c(5,5,6,6,7,7, 8,8)` or some other character values.

Comment: I see, then it's just `setDT(df)[, c('b', 'd') := .(arg1[.GRP], arg2[.GRP]) , by = .(a)]` then, no?

Comment: @DavidArenburg The OP also wanted a copy of 'a' column as 'b'

Comment: sorry, this was an old piece of code, I don't care about b.